# UIWebView not display images contained on the web site properly

Tags: image, uiwebview, ios6

I'm using iOS 6. My application open a seperate view which has an `UIWebView`. But the problem is images are included on the web site are cut off. What is the reason for this and how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's likely the website you're loading is not designed to be responsive, so its being cut off by the width of the UIWebView.

Try enabling "Scales Page to Fit" and see if that helps.